# How to Update a Listbox from another Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have two listboxes in two separate forms Once one is filled out and a button click event is used I want the data from that listbox in this instance a bunch of scores to be transmitted to the other form. My issue thus far is converting my listbox in my second form to an arraylist.

Code Below:

Form1

```
Form3 newForm1 = new Form3(this); 
newForm1.ShowDialog();

foreach (string s in newForm1.updateStudentInfo)
{
    listForm1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Form2:

```
public List<string> updateStudentInfo { get; set; }

    string student = txtName.Text;
            string[] stuffFromList = listboxscores // Unsure how to transfer into an arraylist


            for (int i = 0; i < stuffFromList.Length; i++)
            {
                student = student + "|" + form3.listForm1.Items.Add(stuffFromList[i]);
            } 

            updateStudentInfo.Add(student);
            form3.listForm1.Items.RemoveAt(form3.listForm1.SelectedIndex);
            this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry For any confusion I have students in the main Form looking like so Jame|22|45|66 when we press update it moves to another form with a name textbox and the scores of the student in a listbox. Once they are edited I press the OK button and currently it only transfers the name back and I need to scores too also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you really need help with is getting list box items into an array/list? This should do it:
This of course is assuming your rest of the code works.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
if (lbScores.Items != null && lbScores.Items.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in lbScores.Items)
    {
        items.Add(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here I rewrote the code so you could better understand.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string student = txtName.Text;
    if (lbScores.Items != null && lbScores.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in lbScores.Items)
        {
            student = student + "|" + item.ToString();
        }
    }

    updateStudentInfo.Add(student);
    form3.listForm1.Items.RemoveAt(form3.listForm1.SelectedIndex);
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Which Form would this go in sorry? new to C# bear with me.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, but this code should go in place of: `string[] stuffFromList = listboxscores.Text; // I don't know what to do here`.

Comment: So Sorry I am new to this site I am need to make things more concise

Comment: Please rewrite your original questions clearly defining your problem and what you want to do, then I can better help you. As it is, it's very difficult to understand.

Comment: In my string[] array I need stuffFromList for my For loop what do I use to replce that as I use your foreach loop above it?

Comment: Does that make sense Sach?

Comment: No it does not. Like I said, please rewrite your original question clearly defining your requirements. Please learn how to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Hopefully that's better and thankyou for bearing with me

Comment: Do you mind if you have the spare time since it works can you comment it so I can understand How that orchestrates and works please?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand you. And now your original code sample doesn't even compile. Please slow down and first read the link I posted above and learn how to post a question where _others_ can understand.
In your original question, explain these: how many forms do you have? How many listboxes do you have? Which list box is in which form? What data do you want to move, from which list box to which, and from which form to which? At what event-trigger do you need this to happen? Don't comment here anymore, please go back and edit your original question.

Comment: Edited now hopefully somewhat better or my second question

Comment: So if what you really need help with is getting list box values into an array or a list, my code sample should work. Simply, replace your `btnOK_Click` method code with my second code sample.